# How to convert a String to an existing identifier in java?

Tags: java, swing

```
private ImageIcon grasslevel0 = new
    ImageIcon("/home/vishnu/workspace/game/bin/grasslevel0.png");
JButton k = new JButton("");
k.setIcon("grasslevel"+i);
```

I need to convert the string `"grasslevel"+i` to identifier. Is that possible?
If not please provide an alternative.

Comment: You need an array or collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private ImageIcon[] grasslevels = new ImageIcon[42];
for (int i = 0; i < grasslevels.length; ++i) {
    grasslevels[i] = new ImageIcon("/home/vishnu/workspace/game/bin/grasslevel"
        + i + ".png");
}
JButton k = new JButton("");
k.setIcon(grasslevels[i]);
```

If the number of icons is not fixed, use a `List<ImageIcon>` instead of `[]`, see the answer of @Anuswadh; with `grassLevels.add(new ...)` and `grasslevels.get(i)`.

**The reason for this approach over a theoretical string-to-identifier, is the type-safeness; that the compiler/IDE can decide the correctness. And support typing with auto-completion.**

Answer (score 4):

You always need to manually name the identifier. But you can use arraylist to store the objects.

```
 ArrayList<ImageIcon> grassLevel = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
 grassLevel.add(new ImageIcon("/home/vishnu/workspace/game/bin/grasslevel0.png"));
 grassLevel.add(new ImageIcon("/home/vishnu/workspace/game/bin/grasslevel1.png"));
 JButton k = new JButton("");
 k.setIcon(grassLevel(1));//This sets the image grasslevel1.png as the icon
```

Answer (score 0):

That is possible to do with reflections, but is generally not advised.

```
private ImageIcon grasslevel0 = new ImageIcon("/home/vishnu/workspace/game/bin/grasslevel0.png");

JButton k = new JButton("");

try {
    Class c = this.getClass();
    Field f = c.getDeclaredField("grasslevel" + i);

    ImageIcon im = (ImageIcon)f.get(this);

    k.setIcon(im);

} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

k.setIcon(im);
```